# How to make a dummy application reads gzip files (on-the-fly) without code changes

Tags: gzip, read

I'm looking for a general tool/library that overrides the OS fopen function to read gz files seamlessly on-the-fly without modification to an application.

Details: I have a legacy application that reads large binary files. These binaries compress very well as gz. I was thinking of compressing these binary files and keep the original files extension (as required by the legacy application) and use a library or an application that intercepts and overrides the system calls to support reading compressed files without any changes to the application code, and without doing complete uncompress. Also, doing overall filesystem compression is not applicable, as it would kill the performance of other HPC applications. I only need to compress specific binary files which are read by legacy applications, and add support for those applications to read these compressed files without any alteration to the source code.

Is there something available to do such thing? I don't care about portability, as long as it works fine in my Linux distro (RHEL 6)

Comment: If it calls lseek() a lot be prepared for it to work really badly.

Comment: Whether this is remotely plausible depends a lot on whether the application needs random access (`lseek` etc.) or just reads the file sequentially. In the latter case there might be reasonable solutions. In the former, no, just no.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility might be to use some specialized file system. Perhaps a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem (e.g. [FUSE-BGZIP](https://github.com/sahlberg/fuse-bgzip)) which is doing the compression could do the trick, and you could adapt it to only transparently compress the few files you want to (e.g. with some [overlayfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS)).

See also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/617648/transparent-compression-filesystem-in-conjunction-with-ext4) question (transparent compression for ext4).

Comment: Very interesting! a downside maybe is the compressing process not parallel. Today I'm using pigz which is almost 10 times faster than normal gzip especially that our gpfs storage can handle it. Also it depends on FUSE, which out of the box doesn't compile on my system. But, I'll give it a try,

Answer (score 3):

[zlibc](http://zlibc.linux.lu/) seems like it can do what you want.  Here's the description etc from the debian package of it:

```
Package: zlibc
Version: 0.9k-4.3
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5)
Description-en: An on-fly auto-uncompressing C library
 Zlibc is a preloadable shared library that allows executables to
 uncompress the data files that they need on the fly. No kernel patch,
 no recompilation of these executables and no recompilation of the
 libraries is needed.
Homepage: http://zlibc.linux.lu/
```

I have no idea how well it works, or if it's still being maintained, or if there's an RHEL6 package of it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for. It seems like it's not actively maintained, but I'll get the source code, compile it and give it a try.

Comment: The methods zlibc uses are extremely hackish and will badly break (possibly in subtle ways you don't catch right away) callers who don't adhere to undocumented new rules for how they can use the standard file access functions. This is not a good solution.